# Facebook API post to event wall cronjob

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app which allows users to create events or use pre-created events. Each event has a playlist.

I need to run a cronjob everyday that checks for all playlists and posts a reminder to the event wall if the playlist doesn't contain anything.

Am I able to post messages to the event wall this way as there will be no user authentication and Im not sure how I would do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Posting on an event wall can only be done by an authenticated Facebook user account.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert so the app itself cannot post to an event wall unless a user is involved?

Comment: Yes. The app has no power on Facebook. It only uses the user abilities to do what is needed. That depends on the authorizations the app asked and the authorizations the user accepted.